# How to fix undefined method error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting an error saying: undefined method `androids_path' for #<#:0x007ff5edcd5330>.  It's saying the error is at line 1 in new.html.

The name of the model is Android and is at android.rb.  Any advice on how to fix this?

In androidapps_controller.rb:

```
def new
    @android = Android.new
end
```

In new.html I have:

```
  <%= form_for(@android, validate:true) do |f| %>
<% @android.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>

<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Grabapp::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'iosapps#index'
get "static_pages/home"

get "static_pages/add"

get "static_pages/about"

devise_for :users
resources :iosapps
resources :androidapps
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: just included routes.rb

Comment: You need to add 'resources :android'

Comment: you might want to add `url` as an option to form_for.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: @RadBrad, you should post your comment as the answer.

Comment: sorry, but are you sure you've showed up all `new.html.erb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your routes.rb:

```
resources :android
```

You're error is because you've asked form_for to do resource based routing!

```
<%= form_for(@android, validate:true) do |f| %>
```

But you didn't define the resource based routing required to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

Your model and controller are not matched (Android vs AndroidApp), so need to specify the correct url in your form:
`<%= form_for(@android, validate: true, url: androidapps_path) do |f| %>`

`<%= form_for(@android, validate:true) do |f| %>` automatically sets up the correct HTTP method (normally POST or PUT) with the HTML markup for a form. It also assumes you have a url set up called `/androids` in the case of POST and `/androids/:id` in the case of PUT. So for this to work you need to tell rails to create the necessary routings. This is done by adding the following line in `config/routes.rb` namely `resources :androids`.

This is why is is better to match up your model and controller names, Rails can then automatically infer the correct controller actions based on the model name.

You need to read up a bit more on routing and how it works. Do it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html